# Reading URL Parameters

Tags: php, query, http

The following URL call, is redirected and processed by the `404.php` page, indented to capture the `s` parameter.

https://www.example.com/doc/?s=par

For some reason, while try to processing the `s` parameter, none of the following alternatives succeed in reading the string `'par'`,

```
echo 's0: "'.$filename0.'"<br>';
$filename1=htmlspecialchars($_GET['s']);
echo 's1: "'.$filename1.'"<br>';
$filename2=get_query_var('s');
echo 's2: "'.$filename2.'"<br>';
```

It fails when using `doc\`, an empty folder, redirecting to the `404.php`.

When replacing that string with `404.php` or with any not existing folder or file, the problem is not experienced.

https://www.example.com/404.php?s=par

https://www.example.com/not-an-object?s=par

https://www.example.com/not-an-object/?s=par

What I am missing? how should I debug this?

Comment: `s` is already a query variable in core used for search you shouldn't be adding it as a custom query variable. Note that query variables are not URL parameters

Comment: @TomJNowell That is good to know, then I will remove that filter...